# Several async calls in jasmine 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, jasmine

I am trying to make two async call in one jasmine test suite. 
The second call should wait until the first one is finished then make a call. 
So simple setup:

```js
it('async tests', function(){ 

runs(function() {
      flagToServer = false;
      flagFromServer = false;
      value1 = 0;
      value2 = 0; 
      dataToGet = "";
      dataToSend = "";

      setTimeout(function() {
        flagFromServer = true;
        data = getDataFromServer();
      }, 500);
    });
    waitsFor(function() {
      value1++;
      return flag;
    }, "The Value should be incremented", 750);

    runs(function() {
      expect(value1).toBeGreaterThan(0);
      expect(data).toBe(expectedData);
    });

    //second async call to server;
    runs(function() {
      dataToSend = manipulate(dataToGet);
      
      setTimeout(function() {
        sendDataToServer(dataToSend);
        flagToServer = true;
      }, 500);
    });
  
     waitsFor(function() {
       value2++;
       return flagToServer;
       
     });
  
     runs(function() {
       expect(value2).toBeGreaterThan(0);
       expect(eventFromServer).toBe('got data');
     });

});
```

Is it possible to do something above? I could not find a usage where several waitsFor/runs blocks are used together. Is it the right way to test several async calls one after another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after experimenting with our setup, I have got that it is indeed possible to use several runs and waitsfor in one suit. They will be executed in order they were defined.

```
run(function() {
```

```js
runs(function() {
  async();
})
waitsFor(function() {
  return data;
}, "Data should have come", 2000);

runs(function() {
  expect(data).not.toBeEmpty();
  async(data);
})

waitsFor(function() {
  return manipulatedData;
});

runs(function() {
  expect(manipulatedData).not.toBeEmpty();
});
```

Each respective wiatsFor will wait for condition that should come from their respective run blocks or timeout.